# HTML displaying > instead of end of Text

Tags: html, css, browser, server, apache2

I am pretty much a noob to html, so I am clueless.

I wanted to create a nice-looking, apple iCloud style apache2 server on my Raspberry Pi 4. I have basic HTML skills, so I found a nice font and ended up with a reasonable prototype. Here is the page with the problem:

In my Chromium browser, it looks like this:

```
Home /

Hey Family! This is a server set up by Ted to share files around the house.
Please email me at mrtedlloyd@gmail.com if you want to add a file.

Choose a directory to get going. Please note this cloud server only works on our WiFi.

- Music [Music, DIRECTORY]
For phones or tablets, please hold your finger on the link to download it.
For desktops, please click on the link, and then hit CTRL + S, and follow the 'save as' instruct>
```

As you may have noticed, the rest of the save as instructions do not show, and finish with a >.
The bottom 2 lines appear on the bottom of every page, so it is quite noticeable.

Just thinking about it, I had the noobish brainwave of hitting CTRL + SHIFT + I ; which, for the people who don't know, opens up google's developer tools. In the page's html from the browser, it appears with the >. So it is reading it wrong? Wrong encoding? I think I'm currently on UFT-8.

I will also provide my stylesheet; master.stylesheet.css, just in case that's the problem (which I very much doubt.):

```
import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Share+Tech+Mono&display=swap');
body {
font-family: 'Share Tech Mono',  monospace;
}
p.breadcrumb {
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
p.breadcrumb a {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
p.breadcrumb a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Any answers appreciated. Note: I am 10 years old, so make it simple if you can.

UPDATE: My noob html skills are bad. I put `</br>` instead of `<br/>`
Here is the fixed code:

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <title>Lloyd Family Cloud Server</title>
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.stylesheet.css">
        </head>
                <body>
                        <p class="breadcrumb">
                                <a href="">Home</a> /
                        </p>

                        <p class="intro">Hey Family! This is a server set up by <strong>Ted</strong> to share files around the house.<br/> Please email me at <a href="mailto:mrtedlloyd@gmail.com">mrtedlloyd@>
                        <p class="intro">Choose a directory to get going. Please note this cloud server only works on our WiFi.</p>

                        <nav>
                                <ul>
                                        <li><a href="Music/">Music [Music, DIRECTORY]</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </nav>
                        <p class="instructions">
                                For phones or tablets, please hold your finger on the link to download it.<br/>For desktops, please click on the link, and then hit CTRL + S, and follow the 'save as' instruct>
                        </p>
                </body>
</html>
```

So i'm cool about it now. Thanks everyone!

Comment: The fact that the text is different between the code and the result is pretty suspicious.  I suspect you've made a mistake in your debugging of the problem.

Comment: I noticed that a </br> tag in your p element, it should be <br/>.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose it's just a typo. Please read the source HTML file again carefully.

- Certain characters (`<, >, &, "`) have a special meaning in HTML. For cases where you need to use the character as a part of regular text, there are [HTML entities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity), for example instead of `<` you use `&lt;`.
- [Some elements don't have an ending tag](https://www.thoughtco.com/html-singleton-tags-3468620), they are called singleton tags or void elements, you used `</br>` but there is no opening tag so I suppose it's just a typo.

Comment: I am so grateful! the '</br>' to '<br/> 'change  got rid if the >. Thanks so much!